# Keeping record of the result of Google's “I’m feeling lucky”

Tags: google-search

The button “I’m feeling lucky” in Google directs you straight to the first search result. That link changes with, at least, user and time. I might be interested in keeping proof about what that link was for me, at a given time.

Is there any way of storing that resulting link, in a way that it is guaranteed it was the actual link returned by Google (i.e., that it is not confused/tweaked)?

Comment: The "I'm Feeling Lucky" button is now mostly a little Easter egg. Mouse over it and it changes to "I'm feeling generous" or "I'm feeling puzzled" and so on. Clicking it takes you to one of a number of Google experiments, games, or items of interest in, say, Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For personal purposes, use one or any combination of the following:

- [bookmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmark_(World_Wide_Web))
- [screencast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast)
- [macro recording](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_recorder)

For other purposes, besides the above, could be necessary a controlled environment an a notary.